# Multiple tailwind configuration build error

Tags: css, vue.js, sass, tailwind-css, laravel-mix

I have a problem to build two separate css files with Laravel Mix

In general we start build new product and we need completely different design for public and admin part.
For that reason I need to build 2 css files (admin and public from scss). For both of them I use different tailwind config file.

```
mix
.sass('resources/Admin/sass/admin.scss', 'public/css/admin.css').options({
    processCssUrls: false,
    postCss: [tailwindcss('admin.tailwind.config.js')]
})
.sass('resources/Public/sass/public.scss', 'public/css/public.css').options({
    processCssUrls: false,
    postCss: [tailwindcss('public.tailwind.config.js')]
})
```

When I try to build those files separately there in no problem. Everything is loop perfect.

But when I try to chain them depends of order I get a error

"The `border-theme-5` class does not exist, but `border-red-50` does. If you're sure that `border-theme-5` exists, make sure that any `@import` statements are
being properly processed before Tailwind CSS sees your CSS, as `@apply` can only be used for classes in the same CSS tree." if admin file is first

or if admin file is second build is successful but design is broken.

I think that I need to clear temp file or something similar between two sass calls but can find anything related as a answer here.

Comment: [Brandon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10459109) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66961325) saying "I was trying to do something similar. This helped me. [https://blog.adaptivemedia.se/multiple-tailwind-config-files-for-one-app-tailwindcss-10](https://blog.adaptivemedia.se/multiple-tailwind-config-files-for-one-app-tailwindcss-10)"